# Multiplying values in same position in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataset, logic

I am working in **R** and I have two datasets.  One dataset contains a contribution amount, and the other includes an include/exclude flag.  Below are the data:

```
> contr_df
     asof_dt    X          Y
1 2014-11-03   0.3         1.2
2 2014-11-04  -0.5         2.3
3 2014-11-05   1.2         0.4
> inex_flag
      asof_dt  X    Y
1 2014-11-03   1   0
2 2014-11-04   1   1
3 2014-11-05   0   0
```

I would like to create a 3rd dataset that show one multiplied by the other.  For example, I want to see the following

```
2014-11-03 0.3 * 1       1.2*0
2014-11-04 -0.5*1         2.3*1
2014-11-05 1.2*0         0.4*0
```

So far the only way that I've been able accomplish this is through using a for loop that loops through the total number of columns.  However, this is complicated and inefficient.  I was wondering if there was an easier way to make this happen. Does anyone know of a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the multiplication, but doesn't make sense for factors:

```
df1 * df2
#  asof_dt    X   Y
#1      NA  0.3 0.0
#2      NA -0.5 2.3
#3      NA  0.0 0.0
#Warning message:
#In Ops.factor(left, right) : * nicht sinnvoll für Faktoren
```

One Option: You can cbind the first column and the multiplied values like this:

```
cbind(df1[1], df1[-1] * df2[-1])
#     asof_dt    X   Y
#1 2014-11-03  0.3 0.0
#2 2014-11-04 -0.5 2.3
#3 2014-11-05  0.0 0.0
```

This means, you multiply the df1 and df2 without their first column of each data frame and add to it the first column of df1 with the dates.

Answer (score 2):

The one-line answer is:

```
mapply(`*`, contr_df, inex_flag)
```

This will pair-wise apply the scalar multiplication function across the data.frame columns.

```
d = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(0,2,-1))
e = data.frame(a=c(.2, 2, -1), b=c(0, 2, -2))
mapply(`*`, d, e)
      a b
[1,]  0.2 0
[2,]  4.0 4
[3,] -3.0 2
```